# iPad app in production not requesting user consent for push notifications

Tags: ipad, push-notification

Our ipad app is not requesting user consent for push notifications -- Without the user's consent we cannot receive the device token of the user. We tested during the sandbox phase and an alert box *was* displayed. We have also successfully deployed many, many iphone apps into production with the push notification feature. This is first ipad app to allow push notifications. We are almost positive that the release of our most recent ipad app is not requesting (via an alert box) consent from the user for push notifications.

I am trying to debug this -- what are possible reasons that this would not work? We need the app to show an alert box during the wake up or launch of the application.

Comment: Just a note that during our testing phase we had no problems with the push notification alert box -- on our sandbox app, an alert box _was_ displayed that requested user consent. Only the production app is having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

These steps may help:

1. Delete the app from the iPad.
2. Restart the iPad.
3. Do Build/Clean All Targets in Xcode. Then delete the Build/ directory.
4. Build the app again to the iPad.

This has worked for me on occasion.

Comment: Thank you -- but we are not having problems in the simulator or in the sandbox. This is a production issue. We would not have submitted to Apple if we knew there was a bug with push notifications. We are only seeing this problem on the live/production apps only.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you run it on the simulator. Without any code to go by, this is all that I can suggest. Good luck.